# datatable connection in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I have 2 different Data Tables as shown in screenshot and I wanted to connect these 2 data tables with following conditions

1. BLK_ORIG_CITY_ST.Table A = Origin.Table B
2. BLK_NAME.Table A contains in Test (BlkSeq).Table B.

Please let me know if it possible to connect the two data tables with the relation stated above? If Yes, How ?

**strong text**Spotfire 7.0.1

[Table A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXqyD.png)
[Table B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lw8o8.png)

Comment: whats the source of the data? Excel, Oracle, SQL, etc?

Comment: SQL is the source.

Comment: Do you have write access to the DB (can you create a view, stored procedure, etc)? If so it's much easier, if not there's a more taxing way within Spotfire

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have write access to DB. Please let me know how to do it in Spotfire.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @VenkataBhaskarReddy - Instead of connecting these two tables, why not add 'BLK_Name' column to Table B by matching 'BLK_ORIG_CITY_ST' column from Table A and 'ORIGIN' column from Table B. Both conditions will be satisfied.

Comment: @VenkataBhaskarReddy - 'BLK_Name' values always end with '-N'?

Comment: maybe you can provide some example data to clarify your question?

Comment: @ksp585, BLK_NAME doesn't always ends with '.-N'

Comment: Thank you all for taking time and helping me out

Comment: In Table A, if  BLK_ORIG_CITY_ST is SALEM, IL and BLK_NAME is 00248-N,  I should get row 24 from table B as one of my record.

Also, In Table A, if  BLK_ORIG_CITY_ST is SALEM, IL and BLK_NAME is LB87-N, then also, I should get row 24 from table B as one of my record.

Please get back to me if you need more info. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to Relationships in the data table properties and match the columns that contain cities.